# Postfix replaces "from" when using simple filtering

Tags: postfix, filtering, address

I'm trying to configure Postfix (on a RHEL 6.5) to modify the content of incoming messages and forward the emails to a remote server.
I used a Perl script piped to Postfix to modify the content, and the emails get injected back into Postfix using Sendmail.

When the email first comes to the server, I see the `from` field being initialized correctly, but then it gets rewritten:

```
postfix/smtpd[29150]: connect from ** local domain **[x.x.x.x]
postfix/smtpd[29150]: 2CF665F6B9: client=** local domain **[x.x.x.x]
postfix/cleanup[29155]: 2CF665F6B9: message-id=<msg_172345>
postfix/qmgr[29120]: 2CF665F6B9: from=<original_sender@external.domain>, size=66895, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
postfix/pickup[29119]: 472C75F6BC: uid=600 from=<admin>
postfix/cleanup[29155]: 472C75F6BC: message-id=<msg_172345>
postfix/pipe[29159]: 2CF665F6B9: to=<correct_recipient@external.domain>, relay=myhook, delay=3.1, delays=3/0.01/0/0.06, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via myhook service)
postfix/qmgr[29120]: 2CF665F6B9: removed
postfix/qmgr[29120]: 472C75F6BC: from=<admin@** local domain **>, size=67025, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
```

As you can see, the `from` field changes from `original_sender@external.domain` to `admin@** local domain **`

I assume that `admin` comes from the pipe `user=admin` in the main.cf, and the local domain is taken from `/etc/hosts`.

What I need here is to keep the original sender of the email, but it seems I'm not able to achieve that.
Could you point me in the right direction?

Thank you so much.

EDIT:

This is my Postfix configuration:

```
postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = $myhostname, localhost
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
myhostname = ** local domain **
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_connection_cache_on_demand = yes
smtpd_helo_required = no
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

It seems that my Postfix doesn't accept the `-M` flag.

This is the **master.cf**:

```
# cat /etc/postfix/master.cf | grep -v "#"
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd 
  -o content_filter=myhook:
pickup    fifo  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
        -o smtp_fallback_relay=
showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
myhook unix - n n - - pipe
   flags=Rq user=admin argv=/var/tmp/filter.pl ${sender} ${recipient}
```

Comment: Do you use a relay to send the mails? Where's your postfix configuration?

Comment: Post the output of `postconf -M`. It'll show how postfix pipe email to your perl script

Comment: I'm actually generating the email using a local tool.

Comment: Thanks, looks like -M parameter was added in newer version. Can you show the content of master.cf file?

Comment: @masegaloeh, added :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the output of `master.cf` above, we know that postfix will passed the original sender on first argument of your script. So, your script will have to parse the arguments, save it to variable and use it to provide sender address when email reinjected to postfix via sendmail command.

Sendmail command accept sender parameter via -f parameter. So your script must call `sendmail -f $origsender ...other parameter`

References:  http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html#simple_filter

Comment: This finally solved my problem, thank you so much!